# Switching from simple queries to prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So this is my first attempt at converting some previously used code to prepared statements in order to prevent SQL injections. I'm using mysqli procedural, as follows,

Old query:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ulogs SET invalid_hits = invalid_hits + 1 WHERE user_id = $link AND date = '$date'"); 
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con) < 1) {            
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ulogs(user_id,date,invalid_hits,unique_hits,non_unique_hits,earned,ref_earned,bonus) VALUES ('$link','$date',1,0,0,0,0,0)");
}
```

Prepared query:

```
 $q1 = "UPDATE ulogs SET invalid_hits = invalid_hits + 1 WHERE user_id =? AND date =?";
$qa1 = "INSERT INTO ulogs (user_id,date,invalid_hits,unique_hits,non_unique_hits,earned,ref_earned,bonus) VALUES (?,?,1,0,0,0,0,0)";


if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $q1)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is", $link, $date);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $ucheck = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
if ($ucheck < 1) {
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $qa1)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is", $link, $date);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
exit();
```

And many more which get triggered under different circumstances but basically the same UPDATE first, then INSERT if nothing was updated.
Apparently it worked as I based my queries on examples from php.net. Apparently...
Because, after about 1 hour later, Apache was returning 500 server errors with php timing out while waiting for data from the db. Whereas with non-prepared queries such thing never happened.

So question is: have I done something wrong here? $stmt was being closed every time, along with $con so I don't know what may have caused the db to hang. Note that the server load did not went up either. It was just php-fpm reaching max clients due processes waiting for the db.

Comment: if you had this code working, **then** the reason is not this code. So you have to ask a question not on the deliberately working code, but on the actual problem you have - 500 error or whatever.

Comment: BTW, you should be using a single INSERT ... ON DUPLIDATE KEY UPDATE query here

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Already looking into that!

Comment: @Ivan Please edit your question to include your whole source code. Also add the full error message you get from apache, you might need to look into the `access_log` or `error_log` file of apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still haven't found WHY my original code for prepared statements ended up crashing the DB few hours later, I did eventually find a SIMPLE and WORKING out-of-the-box alternative by using a popular class made especially for this purpose: https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql

This class is pretty straightforward so even a newbie like myself was able to implement it using the examples found on their Github page.

Special thanks goes out to @YourCommonSense for pointing me in the right direction.